# column only has 1's and -1's sql

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a column in one table that gives me the values I expect as a primary key, in another table I have the same column as a foreign key, but when I query this other table the values that exist are only -1, and 1.

Is this some kind of lookup or index? What is going on here?

Thank you

SQL Server 2014

Comment: how could we know what's going on with the data on your tables?

Comment: My hope is that someone recognizes what is going on (maybe it's common) and can point me in the right direction.